# Django comments redirect from posted/preview

Tags: django, django-comments

Im implementing the django comments app.
What is the best way to redirect to the current page when post is clicked rather than the post page?

I've followed this guide: http://www.omh.cc/blog/2008/mar/9/free-comments-redirection/

My form looks like:

```
{% load comments i18n %}

<form action="{% comment_form_target %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {% if next %}<div><input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" /></div>{% endif %}
        {% for field in form %}
            {% if field.is_hidden %}
                <div>{{ field }}</div>
            {% else %}
                {% if field.name != "email" and field.name != "url" %}
                    {% if field.errors %}{{ field.errors }}{% endif %}
                        <p
                            {% if field.errors %} class="error"{% endif %}
                            {% ifequal field.name "honeypot" %} style="display:none;"{% endifequal %}>
                            {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                        </p>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="post" class="submit-post" value="{% trans "Post" %}" /></p>
</form>
```

My views.py looks like:

```
def comment_posted( request ):
    if request.GET['c']:
        comment_id, post_id = request.GET['c'].split( ':' )
        post = Image.objects.get( pk=post_id )
        if post:
            return HttpResponseRedirect( post.get_absolute_url() )
    return HttpResponseRedirect( "/" )
```

My urls.py looks like:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^other/', include('other.urls')),
    url(r'^live/', include('live.urls')),
    url(r'^photo/', include('photo.urls')),
    url(r'^comments/posted/$', 'photo.views.comment_posted'),
    url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    url(r'^search/', SearchView(template=None, searchqueryset=None, form_class=SearchForm), name='haystack_search'),
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/posted/?c=10

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'other',
 'live',
 'photo',
 'haystack',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/export/mailgrp4_a/sc10jbr/lib/python/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/cserv2_a/soc_ug/sc10jbr/WWWdev/dbe/photo/views.py" in comment_posted
  17.         comment_id, post_id = request.GET['c'].split( ':' )

Exception Type: ValueError at /comments/posted/
Exception Value: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I think i have modified my views.py incorrectly, any ideas?

My app is called photo, my model is called Image.

Thanks

Comment: where did you get that from ? comment_id, post_id = request.GET['c'].split( ':' )

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need your comment_posted view. Instead, i think you should fix your next field:

```
{% if next %}<div><input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" /></div>{% endif %}
```

Here, the "next" hidden input is only outputed if a "next" context variable is set. What you should aim for is:

- have next to be {{ next }} if possible
- fallback on the commented object's absolute url

It could look like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% if next %}{{ next }}{% else %}{{ form.target_object.get_absolute_url }}{% endif %}" />
```

This assume that your model have a properly defined get_absolute_url method.

Note that I figured about form.target_object by reading:

1. the code for the comment templatetag, which i noticed instanciate the comment form with the target object as first argument and
2. the code for the comment form which i noticed stores the passed target object in the target_object attribute, making it available wherever {{ form }} is

Comment: I changed that line, it now takes me to a blank page. How do i set NEXT?

Comment: And what ? I favor form.target_object rather than form.instance.content_object in my update.